What is the difference between register_parameter(requires_grad=False) and register_buffer in PyTorch?
During deep learning Training, the update of declared values with this variable is done under with torch.no _grad().
When learning with ddp, it's the process of obtaining the average for each batch sample at each gpu, so no synchronization is required. Is there a difference between the two? register_buffer performs worse. It's not like gradient is flowing, so I don't know why the performance difference is significant.
example in model init

self.matrix = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(197, 192).cuda(), requires_grad=False)
self.matrix = torch.zeros(197, 192).cuda()
self.register_buffer('matrix', torch.zeros(197, 192))

1 and 3 are same performence, but 2 is different

TL;DR Using nn.Parameter (1) will both register the tensor in the parameters and in the state dictionary of the model while register_buffer (3) will only do the latter. On the contrary, using no wrapper (2) will do neither of those two, this shouldn't be adopted if you are trying to learn these parameters. Lastly using register_parameter is the same as nn.Parameter.




method
state_dict
parameters




1
nn.Parameter
✅
✅


2
torch.Tensor
❌
❌


3
register_buffer
✅
❌


3b
register_buffer(persistent=False)
❌
❌


4
register_parameter
✅
✅




(1) nn.Parameter

nn.Parameter is a subclass of torch.Tensor, they have a very special property when used with nn.Modules [...] they are automatically added to the list of its parameters. Assigning a Tensor doesn’t have such an effect. - docs

The tensor is wrapped with a nn.Parameter which means it will be registered both in the state dictionary of the instance and the parameter list:
class Model1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.matrix = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(197, 192))

Here we define an instance model1 and test if the parameters generator is not empty, then look at its state dictionary:
>>> any(True for _ in model1.parameters())
True # not empty

>>> model1.state_dict()
OrderedDict([('matrix', ...)]) # not empty

(2) torch.Tensor
In that case, the tensor is just an attribute of the class but has no special treatment and will not be considered a parameter of the model, ie. it won't be traversed to fetch parameters or state:
class Model2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.matrix = torch.zeros(197, 192)

Same here, we can test whether the parameters list and dictionary are empty or not:
>>> any(True for _ in model2.parameters())
False # empty

>>> model2.state_dict()
OrderedDict() # empty

(3) nn.Module.register_buffer

This is typically used to register a buffer that should not be considered a model parameter. [...] Buffers, by default, are persistent and will be saved alongside parameters. This behavior can be changed by setting persistent to False. The only difference between a persistent buffer and a non-persistent buffer is that the latter will not be a part of this module’s state_dict. - docs

Buffers can be accessed as attributes using given names.
We register the tensor in the module buffer:
class Model3(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.register_buffer('matrix', torch.zeros(197, 192))

In this case, notice how it differs, the parameters are empty and the state dictionary is not:
>>> any(True for _ in model3.parameters())
False # empty

>>> model3.state_dict()
OrderedDict([('matrix', ...)]) # not empty

By default, the parameter will appear in the state but when the argument persistent is set to False, it won't appear anymore:
self.register_buffer('matrix', torch.zeros(197, 192), persistent=False)

This will lead to an empty dict:
>>> model3.state_dict()
OrderedDict() # empty

(4) nn.Module.register_parameter

Adds a parameter to the module. The parameter can be accessed as an attribute using the given name. - docs

We register the tensor as a parameter of the model, this is the same as nn.Parameter but the difference is the parameter name can be defined programmatically:
class Model4(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.register_parameter('matrix', 
            nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(197, 192)))

Check on the instance:
>>> any(True for _ in model4.parameters())
True # not empty

>>> model4.state_dict()
OrderedDict([('matrix', ...)])


Note: if you set a nn.Parameter with requires_grad to False, that parameter will not be trained even though it will appear in the parameters list!

Superb answer!!
